# Should CPU fan be run at lower power, or from PSU?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I recently bought an overclocking CPU fan for use with my Asus Sabertooth x99 MB. The CPU_FAN pins provide a max of 12W 1A according to the MB manual, but my fan is rated at 14.4W 1.2A, so would it be better to run my CPU fan from the PSU directly, realizing that it will be running at 100% all the time, or run it from the MB and it won't be getting quite as much power as it should?

I'd think that it would be safer to run at 100% all the time from the PSU, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: If fan is rated to consume more then motherboard can give, than yes, feed it directly from the PSU (make sure PSU can handle it as well).

Comment: Is this a 3-pin fan or a 4-pin fan?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 3-pin, but the fan speed can be altered through the BIOS I think

Comment: Only if you use 4 pins

Answer (score 2):

It would be safer to run your CPU fan from the PSU directly because you don't want to draw more then the rated current from the motherboard.

I've not tried this, but if I were inclined to hack it, I might connect the red and black wires to the PSU and the yellow pin to the motherboard (assuming red,black and yellow wires, if the wires are black yellow and green, black and yellow go to PSU, green to Motherboard) - in that way I expect you would get the required voltage and current safely, and still have the motherboard monitor the speed.

Comment: See http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=652215 (old, but  advises not to draw too much power from motherboard for fans - which I think is common sense - it must cause instability to the motherboard at minimum if you draw more then it can handle)

Comment: With a minor edit (which I made)  this answer is correct. Note that if it's a PWM header (4 pins) the voltage is always the same (12 volts); the PWM signal from the board controls the fan speeds, despite the constant voltage. The rapid switching of power to implement PWM happens inside the fan. btw, if you don't want to "hack" this, you can buy a little adapter that will do this for you. Here's one: https://www.amazon.com/Splitter-Molex-headers-CONNECT-MULTIPLE/dp/B009D3HV1Q/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1536869039&sr=8-8&keywords=multiple+fan+connector  It'll work on non-PWM fans too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd run it from the motherboard. Modern motherboards are *very* good about running fans at the 'right' speed for the current temperature, and you can set a suitable fan speed curve. You *can* run your fan at 100% off the motherboard, and you have much better control

There's no practical advantage to running your CPU fan at 100% all the time.

The only exception here would be for watercooling where your system may have its own control option.

Comment: It won't hurt anything even though the MB doesn't supply the fan with enough power?

Comment: "Enough" ... your fan is relatively low current/voltage. It should be fine.

Comment: No. No. No. The fan is rated for 1.2 amps and the mobo fan port for only 1A. Doing this runs a risk of burning a trace inside the board, perhaps doing other damage.